# Refer to the last founded element jQuery object

Tags: jquery, dom, find

Let's say I have this html structure:

```
<div class="Parent">
<span class="current">Text</span>
<ul>
<li class="0">Cat</li>
<li class="1">Dog</li>
<li class="2">Cow</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And I have this same structure a few times on the page.

Now I want to change each one of the `$('.current')` content to the content of his closest `$('.0')` content.

Can I do it without using a loop? and somehow refer to the last `.find` result? (something like:

```
$('.parent').children().find('.current').html($(refertolastresultsomehow).closest('.0').html());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I do it without using a loop?

No, you will need a loop. *However* you can 'hide' the loop by providing a function to the `text()` method. jQuery will then do the looping over the `.current` elements for you. Try this:

```js
$('.current').text(function() {
  return $(this).closest('.Parent').find('.0').text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Parent">
  <span class="current">Text</span>
  <ul>
    <li class="0">Cat</li>
    <li class="1">Dog</li>
    <li class="2">Cow</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="Parent">
  <span class="current">Text</span>
  <ul>
    <li class="0">Foo</li>
    <li class="1">Bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help